# How to count just first paragraphs with explode()

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have problem when Paragraph is in Blockquote, so I don't want to count those paragraphs. Basically, i want to exclude `blockquote`

```
$banerAfter[2] = "<div>nineth</div>"; //display after the second paragraph
$banerAfter[6] = "<div>nineth</div>"; //display after the sixth paragraph
$banerAfter[9] = "<div>nineth</div>"; //display after the nineth paragraph

$content = "<p>First paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Second paragraph</p>";
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$count = count($content);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
  if ( array_key_exists($i, $banerAfter) ) {
    echo $banerAfter[$i];
  }
  echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy remove the `<blockquote>` tag and its content with [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$content = "<p>First paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Second paragraph</p>";   
$content = preg_replace("/<blockquote.+?<\/blockquote>/i", "", $content);
$xpl = explode("</p>", $content);
echo $count = count(array_filter($xpl));
```

Result:

```
2
```

`array_filter` is needed to clean the array because `explode` maintain also the empty string after the last `</p>` in your string.

Comment: I like your answer better. preg_replace is much faster than what I suggested haha

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried that with something like `<p>Count this <blockquote><p>but not this</p></blockquote><p>...but this</p><blockquote><p>...but not this</p></blockquote>` - I suspect that's greedy and will therefore "gobble up" that middle `<p>... but this</p>` and not count it.

Comment: ... and should't you be after a count of `2` - it's supposed to exclude paragraphs inside blockquotes isn't it?

Comment: @CD001 did you downvoted? It's clear that the OP want to exclude blockquote "I have problem when Paragraph is in Blockquote"

Comment: I didn't downvote yet, but as I understand the question, the OP is trying to exclude `<p>`s inside blockquotes from the count... so you shouldn't be counting `<p>Don't count me<p>`

Comment: @CD001 see my edit, there was an error on the counting method used in the OP code.

Comment: You've still got the problem with your blockquote match being greedy - `$content = "<p>First paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Second paragraph</p><p>Third paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Fourth paragraph</p>";` gives **2** when it should give **4**.

Comment: ... there you go ;)

Comment: @CD001 I edited with `.+?` to make it lazy, thanks.

Comment: @CD001 many thanks for the help, patience and support. Have a good day!

Comment: @user2342558 Is it possible to not delete blockquote from variable? Because i need to show that html after

Comment: @user2342558 I update code in question. Also really Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the content between `<blockquote>` with a `preg_replace`.

Try this:

```
$content = "<p>First paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Second paragraph</p>";   
$content = preg_replace ("/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/i", "", $content);
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$count = count($content);
echo $count;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Is it possible to not delete blockquote from variable? Because i need to show that html after, i update my code in question

Answer (score 0):

Also this is one way to do it

```
$content = "<p>First paragraph</p><blockquote><p>Don't count me</p></blockquote><p>Second paragraph</p>";
$p = array_values(array_filter(preg_split("/\<\/?\w+\>/", $content)));
echo strlen($p[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Is it possible to not delete blockquote from variable? Because i need to show that html after, i update my code in question